# How to store the user selected input from a Listbox

Tags: python-2.7

This is much like a traveling salesman problem. I have a Listbox with college names in it(backed with coordinates I grabbed from the Facebook Graph). I have the selection mode set to multiple. I need to know the code that will allow me to use the colleges they selected so i can put them through a distance method. I only need to know the code to see what they selected. I tried using curselection() but I still do not understand it.

Here is some code:

```
    self.listbox = Listbox(self.mid_frame,width = 42,selectmode ="multiple",
                                        highlightcolor = "orange",
                                        highlightthickness = "10",bd = "5")

    coordinates = []
    collegelist = []
    f = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    # grab the college's lat and long from facebook graph
    for identity in f:
        urlquery='https://graph.facebook.com/'+identity
        obj = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(urlquery))
        college = obj["name"]
        latitude = obj["location"]["latitude"]
        longitude = obj["location"]["longitude"]
        coordinates.append((college,latitude, longitude))
        collegelist.append(college)

    #sort the colleges so they appear alphabetical order
    sortcollege = sorted(collegelist)
    #fill Listbox with the College names imported from a text file
    for college in sortcollege:
        self.listbox.insert(END, college)

    self.listbox.pack(side = LEFT)
    #The label where I would put the total distance
    self.output_totaldist_label = Label(self.mid_frame,
                                    width = 11,
                                    textvariable = self.totaldistance)
    self.totaldistance = StringVar()
    self.output_label = Label(self.mid_frame,
                              textvariable = self.totaldistance)
    self.output_totaldist_label.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.output_label.pack(side = LEFT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been nice to see how you tried curselection to see what went wrong.

Something like:

```
for idx in self.listbox.curselection():
    selitem = self.listbox.get(idx)
```

should do the trick. Have you tried that?